# Replacing Asynctask in existing projects without much code changes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Our project is 5 years old project in Android native.In that we have used Asynctask to make an API call in each and every screen.

As per the documentation Asynctask got deprecated from Android 11 onwards. Currently our project is in play store and there are n number of active users.And it's working fine with android 11 devices also without any issues

Here I have 2 queries

1)Still Asynctask is working fine with Android 11 OS and below versions.Will it affect android 12 OS.I haven't get any clear information about completely removal of Asynctask in android developer site also.
Do I need to take this as serious and have to update my whole project with the replacement of Asynctask?And will it affect upcoming OS versions?

2)If I want to replace that means what will be the best option without making much code changes. Even google suggested some API frameworks like concurrent and coroutines as the best replacement.But I didn't get idea about replacing in existing classes.Because in and every class we are calling AsncTask to make API call.and in onpostexecute we are handing response parsing.

Please suggest some alternate options which will not make much code changes and effective performance..

Thanks in Advance.......

Answer (score 0):

> Here I have 2 queries

Just 2? You sure about that?

> 1)Still Asynctask is working fine with Android 11 OS and below versions.Will it affect android 12 OS.

It's highly unlikely.

> I haven't get any clear information about completely removal of Asynctask in android developer site also.

Correct. One would assume (hope) Google would make a very public announcement if and when they decide to remove it completely.

> Do I need to take this as serious and have to update my whole project with the replacement of Asynctask?

You need to take this a warning that you should stop using `AsyncTask` and replace its use in your code *if you have time*.

> And will it affect upcoming OS versions?

No one but someone at Google could answer that, and they're not going to.

> 2)If I want to replace that means what will be the best option without making much code changes. Even google suggested some API frameworks like concurrent and coroutines as the best replacement.But I didn't get idea about replacing in existing classes.Because in and every class we are calling AsncTask to make API call.and in onpostexecute we are handing response parsing.

"The best option" is going to depend on your code. Google around for "asynctask to coroutines" or something along those lines and you'll find plenty of blog posts on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to go with "Volley" library as per our project structure. In future is there any chance to deprecate volley like AsyncTask?Any idea?

Comment: That's a question for the developers / maintainers of volley.